# About the efficiency of validatestring

Tags: matlab

Matlab has an API like this
  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validatestring.html
That can check if a string is in a candidate list.

How does it work? Does it do a linear search or a log(n) search?

Comment: How many strings are you checking where the difference between log(n) and n would actually matter? What is your actual issue? Provide a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @horchler I basically use it as Matlab function input parser to check input wellformedness. For example, check if an input enum-like var has the value within a list. n is small for the time being.

Comment: You can check out the code for `validatestring`: type `edit validatestring` in your command window. It does make some calls to internal Matlab classes so only The MathWorks would know. If you want something lighter weight, I suggest trying the `strcmp` family of functions. Can't say much more without a more specific question.